# Convert type of Spring Data JPA Page content

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I am using Spring Data JPA and I have a `PagingAndSortingRepository<Contact, Long>` that uses a `JPASpecificationExecutor<Contact>`. I pass a `Specification` and a `Pageable` instance to the `.findAll()` method of this repository to get a `Page<Contact>`.

However, my `Contact` entity has a lot of extra fields and mappings that I don't need on my front end. So, I have a `ContactDto` that contains only the necessary fields, and I have a method that can convert from `Contact` to `ContactDto`.

```
private ContactDto convertToContactDto(Contact contact) {
    //do the conversion
}
```

How would I go about using this conversion method to convert the `Page<Contact>` to a `Page<ContactDto>`?

I can get the content of the `Page<Contact>` and do the conversion like this.

```
final Page<Contact> contactPage = pagingAndSortingContactRepository
        .findAll(ContactSpecification.findByFirstNmLike(firstNm), pageable);

final Collection<ContactDto> contactDtos = contactPage.getContent()
    .stream()
    .map(this::convertToContactDto)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

But then I am left with a `Collection` instead of a `Page`, and I don't know how to get that `Collection` into the content of the `Page`. Is there a way to do this? Or is there another way to call the conversion on the `Page<Contact>` instance itself?

Answer (score 96, accepted):

Turns out that `Page` has its own `.map()` method, to which you can pass a method reference to do the conversion.

Here is how I ended up doing the conversion.

```
final Page<ContactDto> contactDtoPage = contactPage.map(this::convertToContactDto);
```

The `convertToContactDto` method simply creates and returns an instance of the class I'm trying to convert to:

```
private ContactDto convertToContactDto(final Contact contact) {
    final ContactDto contactDto = new ContactDto();
    //get values from contact entity and set them in contactDto
    //e.g. contactDto.setContactId(contact.getContactId());
    return contactDto;
}
```

Comment: This did the trick. Its much easier than creating a new Page instance and copying the objects.

Comment: @Andrew can you include some sample of the code from convertToContactDto  please?

Comment: Very useful - was much easier then using projections, especially with a PagingAndSortingRepository

Comment: I did like this from inception, but did not work out for me. I am seeing now this solution and everyone is happy. I have a strange java.lang.ClassCastException.
class [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to class ***.model.Schedule ([Ljava.lang.Object; is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap'; ***l.Schedule is in unnamed module of loader 'app'). WTH is this?

Answer (score 6):

It may be the case that a Page transformation is less efficient to perform iteratively, as `Page.map(..)` is likely to do, than with the entire collection in hand.

In this case we can use Spring's `PageExecutionUtils` to do the messy work of reconstructing a page with the transformed content.

```
public Page<TypeB> getPageAsTypeB(Pageable pageable) {
    Page<TypeA> pageA = pagingAndSortingContactRepository(pageable);
    Function<List<TypeA>, List<TypeB>> collectionTransform;

    Page<TypeB> pageB = PageableExecutionUtils.getPage(
        collectionTransform.apply(pageA.getContent()),
        pageable,
        pageA::getTotalElements);
    return pageB;
}
```

Comment: It is unclear from your answer where you are getting "pageable" from ...

Comment: I updated the example code to show that the `pageable` in question was used in the repository query that produced the pre-transformed `pageA`.

Comment: Function<List<TypeA>, List<TypeB>> collectionTransform; what is this? Does not work for me as it required initialization. Please elaborate.

Comment: @matua, it is assumed that you are capable of defining the `List` transformation `Function`, `collectionTransform`.  Remember that the point of this particular approach is to take advantage transformations that are more efficient when you have a group of objects in hand, as opposed to doing one at a time.  If you cannot define a function that is more efficient in this manner, then there is no reason to use it!